# create white margin around pdf document without shrinking

Tags: pdf, printing

I've got the following problem:
I want to print a PDF file as a booklet, using Adobe Acrobat Reader (in a copy shop, they got no better printing software). Unfortunately, Adobe shrinks my file down to the printable area. Instead I want to have it printet 50%(cause it'a a booklet, every page shrinked down by half) the original size, without shrinking any further, the margins simply cut off (just the egde of some pics etc, not important, the size matters)

My idea was, to use a software to create a white margin around every page, covering the stuff in the not-printable-area. Then adobe would not shrink anything down.

Does anyone know a tool for my problem? I couldnt find one. (running on either Windows or Ubuntu)

I would prefer a command line tool, cause I got a bunch of files to print.
Or is there a way to tell adobe Reader to not shrink anything (I know it works with normal printing, just couldnt figure it out with booklet printing)
Or are there any other ideas out there?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i found a solution:

I created a PDF template with a white margin, transparent in the middle.
Using 'pdftk' I can easily set my original file als background of my template.

Done.